# c# instantiate mapping class by name

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, factory

I have standard XML data coming in that represents a purchase order from a customer.  Each customer will populate the XML data differently so I need a separate method to process the order based on their specifications.  My goal is to make this scalable so I used an interface because I would like to be able to create additional classes as new customers are added.

How do I select a different Map class based on the customer?

```
public class XmlPurchaseOrder
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }
    public string MapName { get; set; }
    //...
}

public interface IXmlMapper
{
     CustomerOrder MapToCustomerOrder(XmlPurchaseOrder po);
}

public class  CustomerOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPoId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}

//Maps by customer

public class McClownMap : IXmlMapper
{
    public CustomerOrder MapToCustomerOrder(XmlPurchaseOrder po)
    {
        return  new CustomerOrder()
            {
                CustomerId = "McD123",
                CustomerPoId = po.PurchaseOrderId,
                OrderDate = DateTime.Today
            };
    }
}

public class BkMap : IXmlMapper
{
    public CustomerOrder MapToCustomerOrder(XmlPurchaseOrder po)
    {
        return new CustomerOrder()
        {
            CustomerId = "BxK331",
            CustomerPoId = string.Format("BxK{0}", po.PurchaseOrderId),
            OrderDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
        };
    }
}

public class TacoWorldMap : IXmlMapper
{
    public CustomerOrder MapToCustomerOrder(XmlPurchaseOrder po)
    {
        return new CustomerOrder()
        {
            CustomerId = "TW-33",
            CustomerPoId = string.Format("{0}-{1}",po.PurchaseOrderId, DateTime.Now.Ticks), 
            OrderDate = po.Created
        };
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string xmlFile = "CustomerPo.xml";
        var objStreamReader = new StreamReader(xmlFile);
        var xmlData = new XmlSerializer(new XmlPurchaseOrder().GetType());
        var po = (XmlPurchaseOrder)xmlData.Deserialize(objStreamReader);
        objStreamReader.Close();


        //How do I create the associated class by the MapName specified.

        IXmlMapper t = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(po.MapName));

        var customerOrder = t.MapToCustomerOrder(po);
        //...
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking how you can dynamically instantiate different objects based on the mapName?

Comment: Yes.  Each customer needs to be mapped differently and I would prefer to add new customers in separate classes (DLLs).

Comment: Alright, sounds very similar to what I'm doing right now with the .Net Provider Model.  I'm working on my answer

Comment: Everyone has provided great answers.  I think that the direction that I need to go with is to use a Factory pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some further research and what I needed was a Factory.  This is my interpretation of a demo in a Pluralsight.com video called [Design Patterns Library](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/Description/patterns-library) that was presented by [David Starr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17768/david-starr-elegant-code)

```
public class CustomerMapFactory
    {
            private Type[] _mapTypes;

            public CustomerMapFactory()
            {
                LoadAvailableMaps();
            }
            //Return a newly created Type
            public IXmlMapper CreateInstance(string customerId)
            {
                var t = GetTypeToCreate(customerId);
                if (t == null) throw new Exception("Customer map not found");
                return Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IXmlMapper;
            }

            //Find the map to instantiate
            Type GetTypeToCreate(string customerId)
            {
                return _mapTypes.FirstOrDefault(tpMap => tpMap.Name.Contains(customerId));
            }

            //Identify all Types that use the IXmlMapper
            private void LoadAvailableMaps()
            {
                _mapTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                    .GetTypes()
                                    .Where(t => t.GetInterface(typeof(IXmlMapper).ToString()) != null)
                                    .ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the program that utilizes the factory

```
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Same as above
            const string xmlFile = "CustomerPo.xml";
            var objStreamReader = new StreamReader(xmlFile);
            var xmlData = new XmlSerializer(new XmlPurchaseOrder().GetType());
            var po = (XmlPurchaseOrder)xmlData.Deserialize(objStreamReader);
            objStreamReader.Close();

        //Now utilizing the factory.
        var mf = new CustomerMapFactory();
        var poMap = mf.CreateInstance("BkMap");
        var customerOrder = poMap.MapToCustomerOrder(po);

    }
```

Comment: If you have types that aren't in the same assembly (you mentioned this in your comment) you'll have to change LoadAvailableMaps.

Comment: You are correct, rushonerok.  This model was designed to get me started.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could split the workload, so that your Deserializer decorates the `XmlPurchaseOrder` with a `PurchaseOrderType` (enum) based on the characteristics that determines the purchase order type. If this is determined by the XML structure itself, like via a tag or an attribute, this is a simple task - otherwise subclass the `XmlPurchaseOrder` and introduce a virtual method that "calculates" the type.

The other part of the job is to instantiate the concrete `PurchaseOrder` - this can be simplified using a Factory with one Create method for each kind of purchase order, or more brute force with a big switch on the `PurchaseOrderType` enum.

Answer (score 0):

This makes me think of the Provider Model available through .Net.  I am currently using it to instantiate different API Providers based on their Provider Type.

You can set up a near infinite number of different classes that inherit from ProviderBase and add whatever methods you will need to this class.  Then, you create each .dll to perform whatever functionality you need and since they have all inherited from some similar base class, you can put the primary method to begin processing the functionality in there.

Base class:

```
namespace ProviderManager
{ 
  abstract public class SendProviderBase : ProviderBase
  {
    abstract public void Process(whatever args you need);
  }
}
```

Helper class used to instantiate different Providers

```
namespace ProviderManger
{
public class ProviderManger
{
  private ConfigHandler sendConfig;

  public ProviderManger()
  {
    sendConfig = ConfigurationManger.GetSection("sendProvider") as ConfigHandler;
  }

  public SendProviderBase GetSendProviderBase(string MapName)
  {
    try 
    {
      ProviderSettings settings = sendConfig.Providers[MapName];
      return (SendProviderBase)ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(settings, typeof(SendProviderBase));
    }
    //appropriate catch block and whatever else
}}
```

ConfigHandler code

```
namespace ProviderManger
{
  class ConfigHandler : ConfigurationSection
  {
    [ConfigurationProperty("providers")}
    public ProviderSettingsCollection Providers
    {
      get
      { return base["providers"] as ProviderSettingsCollection; }
}}}
```

Usage in Main for you

```
providerManager = new ProviderManager();
SendProviderManger provider = providerManager.GetSendProviderBase(MapName);
provider.Process(whatever args...);
```

Obviously you could rename SendProviderBase to something more related to what you're doing but I kept that name since it was consistent through my code here.  The only other thing you'll need is a declaration of the .config section used to store MapNames that map to the .dll that is related to it.  Since my application is a web service we have a web.config with the following sections:
Custom Section declaration:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="sendProvider" type="KC.ProviderManager.ConfigHandler, ProviderManager"/>
</configSections>
```

And the Send Provider section:

```
<sendProviders>
  <providers>
    <add name="MapNameX" type="namespace.classname, assemblyname">
```

So basically what this does is you feed `providerManger.GetSendProviderBase(MapNameX)` the name in the web.config and it returns to you (assuming everything else is built correctly) the class found in that assembly.  Then you can call the method found on the base class to begin processing (`provider.Process()`).

The other necessary References are as follows

```
System.Reflection;
System.Configuration;
System.Configuration.Provider;
System.Web.Configuration;
```

This is highly scalable as you can add as many providers as you want as long as they inherit correctly

Or, for a more simplified but still quite scalable solution similar to this check out this  [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/187788/Dynamically-Loading-NET-Assemblies-using-Interface)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way would be to add a config setting for each customer that maps to the type used to process their order.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="Customer1" value="MyApp.Logic.Customer1Processor" />
<add key="Customer2" value="MyApp.Logic.Customer2Processor" />
//etc...
</appSettings>
```

then use Activator.CreateInstance like you have currently.